# "nan" in "kore wa nan desu ka"

Tags: kanji, questions

How do you translate the "nan" in "kore wa nan desu ka" from rōmaji to kanji?

Is "これわなんですか" correct?

Comment: None of the characters you wrote are *kanji*...

Answer (score 10):

First of all, the writing system you are refering to is `hiragana`. Not `kanji`. And no, it would not be これわなんですか。

The correct way to write it would be this:

これはなんですか。

The only real difference here is that the は character, pronounced "ha" normally, is being used as a subject particle in this sentence. So is therefore pronounced "wa" and written as "wa" in Romaji.

Another example is the word こんにちは (konnichiwa) which uses the "ha" character as a "wa", but in this case is not a subject marker.

Seperated into seperate words, your sentence is this:

Hiragana: これ　は　なん　です　か

Romaji:....kore....wa...nan....desu....ka

English:....This...*.......what....is**....***

So your sentence literally means: What is this?

If you are looking for `kanji` and not `hiragana`, then the correct symbol would be this:

これは何ですか。

*: wa being used as the subject particle.

**: です（desu) does not always mean "is"

***: ka is a question marker, making the sentence a question.

Comment: very interesting and detailed. would where are we _

Comment: Note that it is possible to also convert これ to kanji - 此れ, but this is seldom used.

Answer (score 4):

何 can be read *nan* or *nani* and it means "what".

"kore wa" means "this" and "desuka" indicates a question.

So "kore wa nan desu ka" basically means "What is this?"

Comment: Aight, so "kore ha nani desu ka" or "これは何ですか"?

Comment: これは何ですか is usually read kore ha nan desu ka in this case.

Comment: Umm, は is the topic particle here, so it is pronounced "wa", even though the hiragana in isolation is pronounced "ha".

Answer (score 1):

In hiragana, これはなんですか。なん is 何 in kanji.
"何" You can read nani, nan. that means **what**.
"korewa 〜 desuka" means **Is this**. (If Japanese sentence has desuka, it is Question)

Anyway, "kore wa nandeska" means **What's this?**